# Validating number and email fields before form is sent

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I am new to PHP so sorry if my question seems a bit noobish. I am creating a contact form which is working great but I need to validate two fields; the phone number and the email address, I need it to check that the phone number field has only numbers and is 11 digits long. The email field needs to be "something"@"something"."something".

If possible I would prefer to do it using only html or php (whichever is easiest), I guess that if there is a way to put the validation into the field properties, that would be the easiest way? eg: in here:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="text" form="contact_form" required/>
```

If that is not possible then maybe in my PHP file which looks like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Submitting...</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$Name = $_POST ['full_name'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Number = $_POST['phone_number'];
$Company = $_POST['company_name'];
$Message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="Name: $Name
\n Email: $Email 
\n Number: $Number
\n Company: $Company
\n Message: $Message";
$recipient = "info@vicarage-support.com";
$subject = "Contact";
$mailheader = "From: $Email \r\n";
ini_set("sendmail_from","info@vicarage-support.com");
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Please try again.");
echo("Form Submitted.");
?>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
setTimeout("location.href = 'http://www.vicarage-support.com/contact_us.html';",3000);
-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Google gave me this => [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://php.net/manual/filter.filters.validate.php) (for part one) --- What were "your" results, and what did "you" try?

Comment: I was trying to find a way of doing it in HTML if possible before jumping straight to PHP because as I mentioned, I am new to PHP and don't have time on this site to be going through trial and error with PHP as it is for a client and needed asap. But, thank you for the link and I will definitely have a look at it on a future project when I have a bit more time to spare, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to check form data *before* submission, i.e. client-side: using JavaScript, and using new (HTML5) HTML attributes for the [`input` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element). They can be used together if desired. Neither of them guarantees valid data; client-side checking should be regarded as convenience to the user, not as a way of ensuring data validity (which you need to check server-side, in this case in PHP code).

The HTML way can be exemplified this way:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="text" form="contact_form" 
   required>
<input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" class="text" form="contact_form" 
   required pattern="\d{11}" label="11 digits">
```

Using `type="email"` means that conforming browsers will check the email address format. This is a nontrivial task. Using `type="tel"` does *not* impose format restrictions (and the format varies by country and authority), but it may make browsers use a better user interface (such as a numeric keypad in touchscreen devices). The restriction is imposed by the `pattern` attribute. The value `\d{11}` means exactly 11 digits. (This is bad usability. I think you should allow spaces, and possibly parentheses and other characters as well, and strip them on the server. It is just too difficult to input an 11-digit number without any grouping. And 11 digits sounds arbitrary.)

There are several approaches to implementing the same in JavaScript. The pattern check is simple, whereas email format checks are very tough, and there are different library routines for it. In general, the check should be fairly permissive, basically just checking that there is an “@” character.

Comment: Thank you, this has helped a lot and I see your point about only allowing 11 digits, how would I write that so it allows a possible "+" (but not essential) for area codes and then a minimum of 11 digits (numbers only) but not limited to 11? I think that should cover everything, yes it is still possible for the number to be wrong but I am less likely to receive spam that way.

Comment: And is it also possible to format the text box if it is invalid? maybe something like "input.text:invalid"?

Comment: Oh and there is reason behind 11 digits, this is a UK site and both mobile and land line numbers are 11 digits long here but if I put the option for a "+" and more then 11 then it will allow for spaces and area codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate this form **before** it is submitted, that will have to be done with javascript. However, you should still check in your server side code, as javascript could be disabled, which would render javascript validation useless.

I've used this in the past, worked well for my needs. 
http://validval.frebsite.nl/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding three variables. First add a `$pattern` variable, then add two variables and use the switch function.

Sort of like...

```
<?php



      $what = what you are checking (phone, email, etc)
      $data = the string you want to check

    function isValid( $what, $data ) {

        switch( $what ) {


            case 'Number':
                $pattern = "/^([1]-)?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i";
            break;
             //Change to a valid pattern, or configure it the way you want.

            case 'Email':
                $pattern = "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,3})$/i";
            break;

            default:
                return false;
            break;
```

This shows you what you want. Now try to validate it like...

```
  }

    return preg_match($pattern, $data) ? true : false;

}

$errors = array();

if( isset($_POST['btn_submit']) ) {

    if( !isValid( 'phone', $_POST['Number'] ) ) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid phone number';        
    }

    if( !isValid( 'email', $_POST['Email'] ) ) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';       
    }

}

if( !empty($errors) ) {
    foreach( $errors as $e ) echo "$e <br />";
}
?>
```

As you can see, this will validate your form. You may have to configure it so the `$pattern` is set ti what you want it to be. This may not be the best way to do so, and I reccomend Javascript, but this is how you could do it with PHP and HTML.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, though I don't have time to dive into PHP on my current project I will definitely use it in the future.